# LAPACK Matrix multiplication with C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, blas

I am fairly new to C++ and trying to use LAPACK libraries for matrix multiplication.
I tried to run the routine dgemm which is give below. I am expecting an output A*B. but every time I get the answer B*A. Is its the way routine works or anything wrong with my code.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void dgemm_(const char *TRANSA, const char *TRANSB, const int *M, const int *N, const int *K, double *ALPHA, double *A, const int *LDA, double *B, const int *LDB, double *BETA, double *C, const int *LDC);

int main(void)
{
    double A[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    double B[4] = {5,6,7,8};
    char TRANS = 'N';
    int M = 2;
    int N = 2;
    int K = 2;
    double ALPHA = 1.0;
    int LDA = 2;
    int LDB = 2;
    double BETA = 0.0;
    double C[4];
    int LDC = 2;

    dgemm_(&TRANS, &TRANS, &M, &N, &K, &ALPHA, A, &LDA, B, &LDB, &BETA, C, &LDC);

    cout << C[0] << endl;
    cout << C[1] << endl;
    cout << C[2] << endl;
    cout << C[3] << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Any inputs will be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like col major vs row major confusion

Comment: @David Heffernan I also suspect the same. Thanks a lot for ur input. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: DGEMM is a BLAS function, not LAPACK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not studied the details of your call to dgemm, and I cannot tell how you are interpreting the result matrix. But it seems pretty likely that you are mixing up col major and row major interpretations somewhere. Most likely the calculation uses col major, but you are assuming row major.

Comment: I did study few details in last couple of days based on ur inputs. dgemm is a BLAS routine based on Fortran. Thus the issue of column major against row major is a definite cause.